# Unable To Display Json Data in html Table Using jquery DataTable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

i have C# function That Return Me Json Formated Data , function is below

```
  void DisplayProjectMasterList()
        {
            string JSONString = "";
            DataTable Dt = DB.GetDataTable("Sp_GetProjectMasterList");
            if (Dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Dt);
            }
            Context.Response.Write(JSONString);
    
        }


and I am Calling This Function Via Ajax  .in console i am getting json data  But i dont know how to pass it to Jquery data table to display.. below is the javascript function... please help Me

function DisplayProjectMasterList() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'project-master.ashx',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'fun': 'DisplayProjectMasterList'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (Chk_Res(data.errorMessage) == false) {
                    $('#tbl').dataTable({
                        paging: true,
                        sort: true,
                        searching: true,
                        scrollY: 200,
                        data: data,
                        columns: [
                            { 'data':data.Prj_Id },
                            { 'data':data.Prj_No },
                            { 'data':data.Prj_Name },
                            { 'data':data.Cus_Company_Name },
                            { 'data':data.Prj_StartDate },
                            { 'data':data.Prj_CompletionDate },
                        ]

                    });
               
             }
        }
        
    });
}
```

i am Getting FOllowing  error while doing So:

DataTables warning: table id=tbl - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: How does your returned data look like in `console.log(data);`?

Comment: Its array of objects

Comment: but is it actually a json data or a string representation of json? if it's a string representation of json then you need to convert it to actual json data before using it. It would be easier if you could post some sample data as well and html markup for table.

Comment: Thanks for such quick replies... I will post the response

Comment: @Pirate Please See What i am Getting In Console...


(15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {Prj_Id: 1, Prj_No: "PROJECT_001", Prj_Name: "MYPROJECTNAME", Cus_Company_Name: "HAMAD J AL-AJMI EST FOR GENERAL CONTRACTING", Prj_StartDate: "2021-01-18T00:00:00", …}
1: {Prj_Id: 2, Prj_No: "PROJ002", Prj_Name: "MYPROJ002", Cus_Company_Name: "HAMAD J AL-AJMI EST FOR GENERAL CONTRACTING", Prj_StartDate: "2021-01-18T00:00:00", …} ............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi make sure the data you are being returned is in the following format:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
     "Prj_Id": 1,
      "Prj_No": 1,
      "Prj_Name": "name",
      "Cus_Company_Name": "company",
      "Prj_StartDate": "2011/04/25",
      "Prj_CompletionDate": "2011/04/25"
    },
{
      "Prj_Id": 1,
      "Prj_No": 1,
      "Prj_Name": "name",
      "Cus_Company_Name": "company",
      "Prj_StartDate": "2011/04/25",
      "Prj_CompletionDate": "2011/04/25"
    }
  ]
}
```

jquery Datatables by default looks for data property for the array of objects
https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Comment: can you tell me how to convert C# datable in such format...   Thanks

Comment: You can try using Newtonsoft JSON and do the following var datajson= new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourcsharpdatatable) } };